# I want to be seen offline on Facebook

Tags: facebook

I am seen online by people although I turn off my chat ability. They keep sending me massages and it's quite annoying. What can I do for that?

Comment: If you are using Facebook mobile App and turned off the chat. It will take some time to update the notification about offline status information to 2nd viewer. So this make the 1st viewer notified as online, but in the next login session from the 1st viewer chat status will be updated as offline.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments there can be some caching as well as delay occurring here. To stay offline ensure all sessions (desktop and mobile) have chat to set offline. You can also try logging out and logging back in to ensure the settings were saved